# Jquery for clicking on filtered data from table

Tags: jquery, automation

The Scenario is :I have to automate the below steps:

Step 1.user search the data form search text box

Step 2.user clicks on resultdata

WebPage contains a datatable having a search text box which filter the result data.so according to the first step:i am using below:

```
 queryString.append("$");
    queryString.append("('.TextBox')");
    queryString.append(".find(':input').val("valueToSearch");
```

so currently ,when i run my test case ,value is entered into textbox but table is not filtering automatically(Manually do).
so seems like i need to trigger a keypress...please suggest.

Comment: What are you testing? How are you running the test? How does the search triggers when you do it by hand? Please, update your question with the required information.

Comment: i am doing web automation using selenium ,for locating the elements i am using Jquery.so above is the query string i have prepared for entering the value inside the table

Comment: for running query, i am using JavaExecuter class

Comment: And how do you trigger the search by hand, in the application, not through automation?

Comment: actually DataTable have thousand of records and filtered automatically when i enterd the value in filter textbox manually,but when i enter the  value through script table is not getting filtered

Comment: You'd need to determine which event is triggering the search and trigger it with selenium controller. If you don't know what the even is, you can always open the browser's console (F12) and trigger different  events with javascript: get the DOM element, and work on it, with regular js, or whatever library you've got available. Sooner or later you'll gues how it's working.